# Passing shell script variables to remote PHP file via curl

Tags: php, macos, shell, curl

Does anyone know the syntax for this?
I have a PHP file that uses argv to turn a parameter into a variable.

If I use:

```
php /path/to/local/phpfile/myphpfile.php variable
```

that works perfectly, but to a remote PHP file:

```
php http://remotehost/myphpfile.php variable
```

I get back:

```
"could not open input file: http://remotehost/myphpfile.php"
```

Fine, so I try with curl:

```
curl --data "variable" http://remotehost/myphpfile.php
```

But the variable does not get passed.
Is it possible to pass shell script variables to a remote PHP file?
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's HTTP. use GET method, Luke

```
curl http://remotehost/myphpfile.php?data=variable
```